# BIRT reporting with apache SolR

Tags: solr, birt

Is it possible to do reporting with BIRT on Apache SolR database ?

I don't know which jar I have to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may give you some ideas:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Can-we-solr-serve-data-to-any-reporting-engine-like-Crystal-Japser-Birt-etc-td4072157.html

The idea is to export Solr data (CSV format was suggested) and consume this in BIRT. I imagine the architecture would be:

DB -> Solr -> BIRT

Although I wonder if ELK using Kibana for reporting, isn't a better model.

https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack